# Creating mfc c++ controls during runtime

Tags: c++, json, dynamic, mfc, dialog

My current project has me attempting to create dialogs based on a .json file.

I want to parse through a .json file and use the information given to construct a dialog in mfc c++ on the fly.

Can this be done? I have never created buttons/edit boxes/drop downs/ect including configuration on the fly.

Thanks in advance for the insight/advice.

Best Regards,

shalld

Comment: Yes, it can be done. But your question is far too broad.

Comment: All of the control classes have a `Create()` and/or `CreateEx()` method that can be used to create these controls on-the-fly (i. e. not through a dialog template).

Comment: Besides the option pointed out by @zet you could also construct an in-memory dialog template from the JSON file, and call [CDialog::CreateIndirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdialog-class#createindirect) on that. That's doable, but a lot of tedious work. Plus, I'm not entirely convinced, that JSON is an appropriate serialization format for a GUI.